# Time doesn't merge with timestamp in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, vector, kibana

I have problem with kibana. Date field @timestamp doesn't merge with Time default field. How to fix this issue. Here is screenshots:[[image]][image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Di3z.png)

I take logs from vector, after parse them to json fields.

Comment: Could you please share your time and @timestamp field in JSON and sample with JSON what is your expectation with merging them?

Comment: Here it is: look

Comment: "@timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
"__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },

Comment: @timestamp is custom field which takes from logs